# Unable to use $.parseJSON on string variable constructed with array variable

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, variables, dynamic

I'm able to successfully parse a variable manually initialized with JSON using jQuery's '$.parseJSON();' but I cannot parse a variable with identical JSON format that was constructed using an array.

Javascript

```
var questionstype = [];
var questionshtml = [];
var questionsquestion = [];
//Store all questions, types, and html for each fieldset into 3 separate arrays
for(var i=1;i<=formpreviewid;i++)
  {
 questionsquestion.push($("#formelement_"+i + " legend").text());
 questionstype.push($("#formelement_"+i).attr("class"));
 questionshtml.push($("#formelement_"+i)[0].outerHTML);
  };
  //alert(questionsquestion[1] + questionstype[1] + questionshtml[1]);

  //format values for each fieldset into values format in mysql
  var questionsvalues = [];
  var index = 0;
  for(var i=1;i<=formpreviewid;i++)
  { 
  questionsvalues.push('{"question":"'+questionsquestion[index]+'","type":"'+questionstype[index]+'","html":"'+questionshtml[index]+'"}');
  index++;
  };
  //alert(questionsvalues);
//questionsvalues = questionsvalues.replace("}{", "},{");
//alert(questionsvalues);

 //format mysql values into JSON format
 var questionsvaluesjson = '{"questions":['+questionsvalues+']}';
```

Using manually constructed string variable with identical JSON format --

```
 var questionsquestion2 = '{"questions":[{"question":"test16","type":"radio", "html":"<input>"},{"question":"test2","type":"checkbox", "html":"<input>"},{"question":"test3","type":"checkbox", "html":"<input>"}]}';

ParseJSON(questionsvaluesjson); //works fine
```

Using string constructed from array --

```
 var questionsvaluesjson = '{"questions":['+questionsvalues+']}';

 Alert(questionsvaluesjson) :

 {"questions":[{"question":"d","type":"radio","html":"<fieldset id="formelement_1" class="radio"><tr><td colspan="2"><legend>d</legend></td></tr><tr><td><label for="1_1">d</label></td><td><input name="radio1" value="d" type="radio"></td></tr><tr><td><label for="1_2">d</label></td><td><input name="radio1" value="d" type="radio"></td></tr></fieldset>"}]}

 ParseJSON(questionsvaluesjson); //Breaks script
```

I am sending this JSON to a php file to be decoded and then used in a foreach loop where I can manipulate the objects to insert the data into a mysql database, but currently it is throwing an error when trying to use object in foreach loop.

Here is the error : 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Here is the code :

PHP

```
foreach ($theArray->questions as $data)
{   
  $insert .= '("' . $data->question . '", "' . $data->type . '", "' . $data->html . '")';
}
$insert = str_replace(")(","),(",$insert);

$query = "INSERT INTO registrationquestions (question, type, html) VALUES " . $insert; 
$mysqli->query($query);
```

Comment: Create your object/array structure with javascript, turn it into json with JSON.stringify, then send that to php. Don't try to create JSON manually.

Answer (score 0):

There are quotes Inside your html strings:

```
"html":"<fieldset id="formelement_1" class="radio">
```

This is totally broken (the string values ends at `id="`).

You need to escape quotes with `\"`.

**EDIT**: of course this is the answer "why it doesn't work". The better way to do it is indeed to serialize your objects with JSON.stringify, which takes care of this issues and others, as suggested in Kevin's comment.

Comment: jods -- actually i am using JSON.Stringify() just before send via ajax. when I do a 'print_r' from php script, this is the response that I get : {"questions":[{"question":"d","type":"radio","html":"<fieldset id="formelement_1" class="radio"><tr><td colspan="2"><legend>d</legend></td></tr><tr><td><label for="1_1">d</label></td><td><input name="radio1" value="d" type="radio"></td></tr><tr><td><label for="1_2">d</label></td><td><input name="radio1" value="d" type="radio"></td></tr></fieldset>"}]} -- this seems to be valid JSON but I can't access it??

Comment: also I just tried temporarily removing html code as a value and replaced with 'test' and still get error:  Trying to get property of non-object in ... throwing error on the foreach loop when trying to access $theArray->questions

Comment: The code posted in your first comment is not valid JSON. It still contains invalid quotes inside your string literals. For the second part I'm curious to see how you did that. I would say the best way to get a precise answer is to post a fiddle of your code.

Comment: Also you say that you use `stringify`, but this is not the code you've posted in your question. You should post the actual, relevant code if you want a good answer.

Comment: turns out it was the HTML part that was messing everything up, also i forgot to use 'questionsvaluesjson = $.parseJSON(questionsvaluesjson)' to before using stringify so it is now working but now I have the issue of getting the HTML code part to work.. I've tried the replace function to replace double quotes but for some reason it doesn't work.. I guess I'll create a new thread for that issue.. I tried to vote your answer correct but I don't have high enough reputation!!!

Comment: Maybe you can't vote up, but because it's your question you should be able to accept it as answer. A tip: I think you're still trying the wrong way. Don't escape quotes and build the string yourself. Build your object model `var x = {questions: [{ html: someHtmlVariable, ... }]};`, then let stringify do all the work: `var json = JSON.stringify(x);`.